# javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'titulo' for locale 'en'

Tags: mvc, spring, spring-mvc, i18n

Estoy tratando de internacionalizar mi aplicacion la cual estoy haciendo con el framework Spring MVC

Este es mi archivo mensajes_en.properties

```
    # To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
# To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
# and open the template in the editor.

titulo = Prueba
```

El siguiente es el archivo dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

<!--
Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
define an explicit mapping for it.
-->
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />

<!-- Internacionalizacion, inicio-->

<bean id="messageSource"
      class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="mensajes" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="languages" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" >
    <property name="interceptors">
            <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>

<!-- Internacionalizacion, fin-->
<!--
The index controller.
-->
<bean name="indexController"

class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
      p:viewName="index" />
```

Mi archivo index.jsp es el siguiente:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Welcome to Spring Web MVC project</title>
</head>

<body>

    <span style="float: right">
        <a href="?languajes=es"></a>
    </span>

    <h1 align="center"><spring:message code="titulo"/></h1>
</body>
```

Pero cuando voy a ejecutar el proyecto, me sale el siguiente error:

> Info:   SpringInternV2 was successfully deployed in 2,359 milliseconds.
>   Warning:   ResourceBundle [mensajes] not found for MessageSource: Can't find bundle for base name mensajes, locale en
>   Warning:   Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
>   javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'titulo' for locale 'en'.
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.MessageTag.doEndTag(MessageTag.java:202)
>       at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.index_jsp._jspx_meth_spring_message_0(index_jsp.java:109)
>       at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:79)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)

Comment: ¿Dónde está *mensajes_en.properties*? Por lo que veo, deberías tener el fichero "mensajes_en.properties" en "/" del classpath (p.ej., si hicieras *Class.getResourceAsStream("/mensajes_en.properties") debería devolverte un *InputStream*).

Comment: Lo tengo en WEB-INF/mensajes

Comment: A ver, ¿el archivo es "WEB-INF/mensajes_en.properties" o "WEB-INF/mensajes/mensajes_en.properties"?

Comment: Es "WEB-INF/mensajes/mensajes_en.properties"

Answer (score 2):

```
<property name="basename" value="mensajes" />
```

Con esto le dices a *Spring* que los ficheros estarán en el classpath, con el package vacío y el nombre base "mensajes" (de donde empieza a buscar *mensajes.properties*, *mensajes_en.properties*, etc.).

Para meter el fichero en el classpath, puedes meterlo tal cual en *WEB-INF/classes* o como un *jar* en *WEB-INF/lib*.

Como es el package vacío, si lo pones en *WEB-INF/classes* deberás poner el fichero en *WEB-INF/classes/mensajes_en.properties*. Si lo pusieras en *WEB-INF/lib*, el *jar* debe tener el fichero *mensajes_en.properties* en la raíz.